# Erro ao usar SSLClientExisEngineConfig

Tags: java

Estou tentando utilizar a classe [SSLClientExisEngineConfig](https://github.com/unkascrack/axis-ssl/blob/master/src/org/apache/axis/client/SSLClientAxisEngineConfig.java)  para fazer uma chamada em um servidor SSL (Eu preciso fazer uma chamada onde o cliente use um certificado para se autenticar ao server, vice-versa). Ao instanciar o objeto mesmo eu definindo quais truststores e keystores chamar, parece que o axis continua utilizando o padrão (Java acerts).
Minha chamada:

```
axisConfig = new SSLClientAxisEngineConfig(abconfigfile);

axisConfig.setProtocol("TLS");
axisConfig.setKeyStoreType("JKS");
axisConfig.setKeyStore("KEYSTORE.jks);
axisConfig.setKeyStorePassword("changeit");

axisConfig.setTrustStoreType("JKS");
axisConfig.setTrustStore("TRUSTSTORE.jks");
axisConfig.setTrustStorePassword("changeit);
```

E ao efetuar a chamada por HTTPS o Axis loga:

> keyStore is : 
>   keyStore type is : jks
>   keyStore provider is : 
>   init keystore
>   init keymanager of type SunX509
>   trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\security\cacerts
>   trustStore type is : jks
>   trustStore provider is :

E tem como retorno:

> AxisFault
>    faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
>    faultSubcode: 
>    faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
>    faultActor: 
>    faultNode: 
>    faultDetail: 
>       {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Gostaria de saber o que pode estar ocorrendo para não estar carregando o KEYSTORE.jks e o TRUSTSTORE.jks
OBS: Consegui através de spring utilizar esse certificado.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que esteja faltando a chamada **axisConfig.initialize()**

```
axisConfig = new SSLClientAxisEngineConfig(abconfigfile);

axisConfig.setProtocol("TLS");
axisConfig.setKeyStoreType("JKS");
axisConfig.setKeyStore("KEYSTORE.jks);
axisConfig.setKeyStorePassword("changeit");

axisConfig.setTrustStoreType("JKS");
axisConfig.setTrustStore("TRUSTSTORE.jks");
axisConfig.setTrustStorePassword("changeit);

axisConfig.initialize();
```